# Javascript not working after type change

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to implement the [Insites Cookie Consent script](https://cookieconsent.insites.com/documentation/about-cookie-consent/) (opt-in version) and load some javascript-scripts after a user has accepted cookies.

Implementing the script isn't a problem, but I keep ending up with no javascript loading. My cookieconsent code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.css" />
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    window.cookieconsent.initialise({
    "palette": {
        "popup": {
        "background": "#252e39"
        },
        "button": {
        "background": "#14a7d0"
        }
    },
    "position": "bottom-left",
    "type": "opt-in",
    "content": {
        "message": "This site uses cookies",
        "dismiss": "I don't want cookies",
        "allow": "I accept",
        "link": "Privacy policy"
    },
                onInitialise: function (status) {
                var type = this.options.type;
                var didConsent = this.hasConsented();
                if (type == 'opt-in' && didConsent) {
                // enable cookies
                    $(".loadlaterscripts").attr("type", "text/javascript");
                }
                },
                onStatusChange: function(status, chosenBefore) {
                var type = this.options.type;
                var didConsent = this.hasConsented();
                if (type == 'opt-in' && didConsent) {
                    // enable cookies
                    location.reload();
                }
                },
    })});
    </script>
```

I implemented a few scripts and widgets with the following code:

```
<script type="text/plain" class="loadlaterscripts" src="//link-to.script/file.js"></script>
```

In the console I can see the type attribute changes to text/javascript successfully after accepting cookies, but none of the scripts will work after that. This happens for example to the Google Adsense script, but also simple embed-codes provided by websites.

Is there something I'm overlooking here?